# AUCTeX/ RefTeX: ignore files by extension

Tags: pgfplots, emacs, auctex, input, reftex

I'm writing a very long document with dozens of figures that are all generated with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and exported as [pgf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) files. Each figure environment then looks something like

```
\begin{figure}
  \input{example-fig.pgf}
  \label{fig:example-fig}
\end{figure}
```

The issue is with commands such as `reftex-reference` (`C-c )`) or `LaTeX-section` (`C-c C-s`). Both of these commands are forced to parse the entire document to do things like build a TOC (`reftex-reference`) or check for conflicting label names (`LaTeX-section`). The problem is that because of all of the pgf files, this parsing sometimes takes forever.

**Question:** Can I somehow make AUCTeX and/or RefTeX completely ignore all `.pgf` files included with a `\input{}` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! A little more digging through the RefTeX manual ([pdf link](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.pdf)) revealed the variable `reftex-no-include-regexps`. Documentation says:

> List of regular expressions to exclude certain input files from
>   parsing. If the name of a file included via \include or \input is
>   matched by any of the regular expressions in this list, that file is
>   not parsed by RefTeX.

Thus, the following line in my `.emacs` fixed the issue:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "reftex-vars"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'reftex-no-include-regexps "\\.pgf\\'")))
```

This add the `"\\.pgf\\'"` to the other entries already present by default in `reftex-no-include-regexps`.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [`add-to-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#index-add_002dto_002dlist-340) in place of `setq`, so you won't override possible future changes to the default value of `reftex-no-include-regexps`.

Comment: I tried that initially, but got errors about `reftex-no-include-regexps` being undefined. I could fix this by putting the `add-to-list` command in the correct hook, but I wasn't sure what hook would be best. I could also add a `require` statement above the `add-to-list`, but I am under the impression that `require` statements are going out-of-fashion with the rise of `package.el`. Is there a better suggestion?

Comment: I added the code directly to your answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a ton for your help!